# (OSStatus) error = -1500 in AudioToolbox Framework

Tags: iphone, audiotoolbox

I am unable to play sound using AudioToolbox Framework.
My line of code :

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
    CFURLRef  soundFileURLRef;
    OSStatus error = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)(aFileURL),         &aSoundID);
```

After debug Show error `((OSStatus) error = -1500)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code -1500 represents the constant `kAudioServicesSystemSoundUnspecifiedError`, which has the description "An unspecified error has occurred.".

I'd double check that the URL can be read by your program, that the destination is a supported format, and that it is a valid, readable file.

Of course, googling `kAudioServicesSystemSoundUnspecifiedError` will give you some additional hints.

Comment: @iphoneProfile those error codes and their documentation is scattered about -- you're welcome :)